# Index out of bounds and multiple runnings

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I'm writing a Conway's game of life program that has left me immensely frustrated for weeks. So far I have written most of the code but am still having some issues. I apologize in advance for the multitude of questions.

My game of life program starts with an input text file that contains 30 x 30 lines of - and X. - representing a dead cell and X alive.

My problems now are:

1. How do I handle the arrayoutofbounds exception when livesurrounding checks out of the array? All I would like to do is ignore those values.
2. How do I change my code to run multiple times for the value of gens variable?
3. Why does printing copygrid always print the address even if I use Arrays.toString?

Thanks, Any help is appreciated as I am so confused and running out of time.

My code:

```
package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author jaw209
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Assignment2 {

    private static int livecount;
    static char[][] copygrid = {{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},{'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'}};        


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inputfile;
        String output;
        String generations;

//Input file = L:\Java 2\Assignment2\Sample input.txt        

//Inputs from file to char array        
        inputfile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Where is the input file?   Ex: C:\\users\\public\\desktop\\input.txt ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader(inputfile)); 
        char[] chararray = new char[900];
        String allvalues = null;

        do {
            String values = input.next();
            allvalues = allvalues + values;
        }
        while(input.hasNextLine());

        chararray = allvalues.toCharArray();

//Reads values in chararray into multi array       
        char[][] grid1 =  new char[30][30]; 
        int i = 4;
        for(int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < 30; col++){
                grid1 [row][col] = chararray[i]; 
                i++;
                    System.out.print(grid1[row][col]);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                    }

//Finds how many generations should be calculated        
        generations = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How many generations should be calculated?");
        int gens = Integer.parseInt(generations);

//Runs the cycle once      
        for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 30; col ++){
                if (status(grid1[row][col])){
                    liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col);
                    moves(row, col);
                }
                else if (!status(grid1[row][col])){
                    //run 3 checker
                  if (liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col) == 3){
                  copygrid[row][col] = 'X';
                  }     
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(copygrid);


//Output to File        
  output = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Where is the output file?");
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(output);      
  out.println(Arrays.toString(copygrid));
    }

//Check to see if cell is live or dead    
    public static boolean status(char value){  
            if (value == 'X'){
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        }

//See if neighbor is alive or dead    
    public static int liveSurrounding(char [][] grid, int a, int b){

        livecount = 0;

        if (grid[a-1][b] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a-1][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        } 
        if (grid[a][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a+1][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a+1][b] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a+1][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (grid[a-1][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        return livecount;
    }   

//Adjust alive cells for each condition    
    public static char[][] moves(int a, int b){

        switch(livecount){
            case 0: copygrid[a][b] = 'X'; break;
            case 1: copygrid[a--][b] = 'X'; break;
            case 2: copygrid[a][b++] = 'X'; break;
            case 3: copygrid[a][b--] = 'X'; break;
            case 4: copygrid[a++][b] = 'X'; break;
            case 5: copygrid[a--][b++] = 'X'; break;
            case 6: copygrid[a++][b--] = 'X';
            case 7: copygrid[a--][b--] = 'X'; break;
            case 8: copygrid[a++][b++] = 'X'; break;
            default:
        }

                    return copygrid;         
    }    
}
```

Comment: For #1: In `liveSurrounding`, you need to decide what the correct logic is when a "surrounding" cell isn't in the array.  Presumably you want to behave just the same as if it's not X.  Then you just need to check the indexes just before accessing the surrounding elements, e.g. `if (a > 0 && grid[a-1][b] == 'X')`, `if (b < whatever-length - 1 && grid[a][b+1] == 'X')`, etc.  A bit tedious, but it's the best way.  Or write a helper method that takes a 2-D array and two indexes as parameters, and does the checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question really is not precise enough, we are not going to look through all your code here, perhaps people over at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) are willing to do that, once your code works...

To answer your problem on how to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you avoid this by **first** checking whether or not the element you want to access is in bounds of the array, and then access it, example:

```
private void accessArray(final int[] array, final int index) {
    if (0 <= index && index < array.length) {
        int whatever = array[index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer #3: `Arrays.toString` works by calling the overridden `toString` on each element.  A two-dimensional array is an array of arrays.  Thus, each element of the array is itself an array, and calling `toString` on an array gives you an address, as it looks like you're aware already.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) of `toString` says:

> If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to
>   strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which
>   describes their identities rather than their contents.

Look into [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Some mistake is there...

1. `char[] chararray = new char[900];` -> you are fixed the length ? is your file contents more than 30 char then `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will come
2. Here you declare `int i=4` of so then **30 x 30 + 4 = 904** and then `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will come

   int i = 4;
   for(int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
       for(int col = 0; col < 30; col++){
          grid1 [row][col] = chararray[i]; 
          i++;
          System.out.print(grid1[row][col]);
       }
   System.out.println();
   }
3. ALSO `if (grid[a - 1][b] == 'X')` if `a=0` than `0-1=-1` so `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will come............. Similarly more and many ....

SO I DO SAY, REVIEW YOUR CODE

Answer (score 0):

For #2: Use this:

```
for(int gen=0;gen<gens;gen++){
    for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 30; col ++){
            if (status(grid1[row][col])){
                liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col);
                moves(row, col);
            }
            else if (!status(grid1[row][col])){
                //run 3 checker
              if (liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col) == 3){
              copygrid[row][col] = 'X';
              }     
            }
        }
    }
}
```